# Error response from daemon, stat overlay no such file or directory after changing docker root location

Tags: linux, debian, docker, docker-compose

I changed docker's data root on my system because the var partition was beginning to fill up, following [this tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-move-docker-s-default-var-lib-docker-to-another-directory-on-ubuntu-debian-linux) but substituting `--data-root` instead of `-g`. After making the switch, one of my docker containers started up and began working just fine, but the rest of them fail with errors like this whenever I try to use the docker compose command for anything:

```
Error response from daemon: stat /home/docker/internals/overlay2/0a2666accf63f7d7c640208cadbf041cc05b0366a4c8134958abadbdabd892f4: no such file or directory
```

It looks like that overlay truly doesn't exist, so I guess the rsync command somehow missed something, how do I recover from this? Is there a way to tell docker compose to recreate its overlay? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: apparently moving docker's root data folder to another place fucked up some of the "pointers" to where state was stored and/or did indeed destroy the overlays, and the way to get them to be recreated was to completely purge all the images and rebuild everything from scratch using the docker compose files. To delete all the images and make everything have to be rebuilt, I used:

```bash
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

and then I just did

```bash
docker compose up -d
```

in each directory. Luckily I didn't lose any important state, because all of that was stored in databases external to the docker container images, as they should be! I love how stateless docker is.